# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Here are some of my snippets of code:
**app.js**:

```
var express = require("express"),
            app = express(),
   mongoose = require("mongoose"),
 bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
 Campground = require("./models/campground"),
     seedDB = require("./seed.js");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static("public"))
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/yelp_camp"); //creating a data base

seedDB();


app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("landing.ejs")
})
app.get("/campgrounds",function(req,res){

    Campground.find({}, function(err, allCampgrounds){
        if(err) {console.log(err)}
        else {res.render("campgrounds.ejs",{data:allCampgrounds});}
    })

});

app.post("/addCampground",function(req,res){
    // var parsedData=
    var name= req.body.name;
    var image=req.body.image;
    var newCampground={name: name, image: image};
    Campground.create({
        name: newCampground.name,
        image: newCampground.image
    }, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err) {console.log(err)}
        else {
            newlyCreated.save();
            res.redirect("/campgrounds")}
    });
f
})
app.get("/campgrounds/new",function(req,res){
    res.render("new.ejs");
})

app.get("/info/:id", function (req, res) {
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundCampground) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            console.log(foundCampground.name);
            res.render("info.ejs", {campground: foundCampground})
        }
    })
});

app.listen(3000,process.env.IP,function(){
    console.log("Server has started");
})
```

and here is my **info.ejs**:

```
<%- include("partials/header.ejs")%>
<div class="container">
    <h3><%= campground.name%></h3>
    <img class="info_pic" src="<%= campground.image%>" alt="...">
    <form action="/comment_add" method="post">
        <textarea placeholder="Comment here" name="add_comment"></textarea>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<%- include("partials/footer.ejs")%>
```

header.ejs:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
    <title>YelpCamp</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <span><a href="/">YelpCamp</a></span>
        <a href="/get-along" class="go-right">Signup</a>
        <a href="/add" class="go-right">Login</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

finally my **app.css**:

```
body{
    background-image: url("https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/000/209/776/small/crumpled-paper-background-1406.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
nav{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}
nav span{
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
nav a{
    color: white;
}
.go-right{
    float: right;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.full-width{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.img-resize{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
}
.info_pic{
    width:50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

I have two queries, one when I start the server, and do a get request for "**/info/:id**", server gets disconnected and following error is returned:

```
D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseO
rCallback.js:19
            throw error;
            ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "app.css" at path "_id" for model "
Campground"
    at model.Query.exec (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4m
mongoose←[24m\lib\query.js:4351:21)
    at model.Query.Query.findOne (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_mod
ules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\query.js:2220:8)
    at Function.findOne (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4m
mongoose←[24m\lib\model.js:2186:13)
    at Function.findById (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4
mmongoose←[24m\lib\model.js:2112:15)
    at D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\app.js:48:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\n
ode_modules\←[4mexpress←[24m\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mexpress←[24m
\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mex
press←[24m\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\n
ode_modules\←[4mexpress←[24m\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mexpress←[24m\lib\r
outer\index.js:281:22
    at param (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mexpress←[24
m\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mexpress←[24
m\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modul
es\←[4mexpress←[24m\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mexpress←[24m
\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4m
serve-static←[24m\index.js:121:7)
←[90m    at SendStream.emit (events.js:310:20)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\
model.js:4893:13
    at D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\
helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
    at D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\
model.js:4914:21
    at D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\
query.js:4382:18
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modul
es\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\query.js:2125:5)
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcam
pdemo\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
    at D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mkareem←[24m\index.
js:369:33
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)←[3
9m {
  messageFormat: ←[90mundefined←[39m,
  stringValue: ←[32m'"app.css"'←[39m,
  kind: ←[32m'ObjectId'←[39m,
  value: ←[32m'app.css'←[39m,
  path: ←[32m'_id'←[39m,
  reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a str
ing of 24 hex characters
      at new ObjectID (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mbs
on←[24m\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
      at castObjectId (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mmo
ngoose←[24m\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mm
ongoose←[24m\lib\schema\objectid.js:267:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo
\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\schematype.js:1031:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdem
o\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\schematype.js:1459:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo
\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\schematype.js:1449:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpc
ampdemo\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\schematype.js:1428:15)
      at cast (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[
24m\lib\cast.js:326:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modu
les\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\query.js:4740:12)
      at model.Query.Query._castConditions (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdem
o\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\query.js:1865:10)
      at model.Query.<anonymous> (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_mod
ules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\query.js:2122:8)
      at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpc
ampdemo\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
      at D:\ujjwal\Ujjwal Web Dev\yelpcampdemo\node_modules\←[4mkareem←[24m\inde
x.js:369:33
  ←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)←
[39m
}
```

Second, my **app.css** is not getting loaded with some ejs files, while it gets loaded with other ones.

Comment: That suggests `req.params.id` does not contain a valid ObjectId string.  Have you tried to console.log that value?

Comment: I see  'app.css'  mentioned in the first line of error. But what has it got to do with ObjectId?

Comment: your `info.ejs` includes `header.ejs` which requests `app.css` at the current path, which well initiate a GET request `/info/app.css` and get caught by your router. Try using `href="/app.css"` instead